# Solving for a variable in an exponential equation

Tags: exponential-function

I have a problem i'm trying to work out and I would like some advice please.

> The intrinsic carrier equation for a semiconductor is the following:
> $$n_i = BT^{3/2}e^{\bigl(\frac{-E_g}{2KT}\bigr)}$$

my question is, is there a way to solve for $T$?
$$\frac{n_i}{B} = T^{3/2}e^{\bigl(\frac{-E_g}{2KT}\bigr)}$$

I would like to take the log natural at some point, but I think you can see what I perceive as my dilemma as T appears twice in this equation.

Comment: Only by numerics.For example:https://brilliant.org/wiki/newton-raphson-method/

Comment: That's good thanks @MariuszIwaniuk I have since found another formula that I can use to get around trying to use this formula to obtain the temperature $T$, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this manipulation
$$
\left(\frac{n_i}{B}\right)^{2/3} = Te^{\bigl(\frac{-E_g}{3KT}\bigr)}\\
\left(\frac{B}{n_i}\right)^{2/3} = \frac{1}{T}e^{\bigl(\frac{E_g}{3KT}\bigr)}\\
\frac{E_g}{3K}\left(\frac{B}{n_i}\right)^{2/3} = \frac{E_g}{3KT}e^{\bigl(\frac{E_g}{3KT}\bigr)}
$$
then use [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$
W\left[\frac{E_g}{3K}\left(\frac{B}{n_i}\right)^{2/3}\right] = \frac{E_g}{3KT}\\
T=\frac{E_g}{3K}W\left[\frac{E_g}{3K}\left(\frac{B}{n_i}\right)^{2/3}\right]^{-1} 
$$

Comment: oh wow, that's pretty cool. I will read about Lambert function in the morning. @enzotib